# I am getting error sending status code in laravel apide

Tags: json, laravel, api

When sending response code in laravel api, validation does not enter.
I can view it from the network, but when I send the status code, the console prints an error and I cannot print the validations on the blade page. If I don't send status code I can print validations.

Following my code: `StudentController`

```
 public function store(Request $request): object
    {
        $validate = Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'name' => 'required',
            'course' => 'required',          
        ]);
        $data = [
            'name' => $request->name,
            'course' => $request->course,           
        ];
        if ($validate->fails()){
            return response()->json(['success' => false, 'errors' => $validate->messages()->all()],422);
        }
        Student::insert($data);
        return response()->json(['success' => true, 'message' => "Registration Successful"]);
    }
```

`ajax`

```
 $(document).ready(function (){
       $('#createBtn').on('click',function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          let form = $('#student-add').serialize();

          $.ajax({
             'url': "{{ route('students.store') }}",
             'data': form,
             'type': "POST",
             success:function (result) {
                 $('#ajax-validate ul').text("");
              if(result.success === true){
                  console.log("True");
              }else {
                  result.errors.forEach(function (item) {
                      $('#ajax-validate ul').append('<li>'+item+'</li>');
                  });
              }
             }
          });
       });
    });
```

`console`

[image]

`network`

[image]

Comment: The code for failed validation should be a [422 Unprocessable Entity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/422) error, not a 404 Not Found error.

Comment: yes you are right but even i sent 422 i get the same error

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to say here... Are you trying to print your errors via JavaScript? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72996000/edit) and include the code that isn't working. To me, this looks completely correct; the `console` tab will output the request and its status (`400`, `404`, `422`, etc), but the `network` tab is where you can view the response. If you want to print out those errors, you'd need to loop over them, like `function(response) { response.errors.forEach(...); }`

Comment: I shared my ajax code

Comment: And this is why you should always share relevant code; `success: function(...)` is never called when a `4XX` or `5XX` HTTP status code is returned from your API. The code you initially shared is perfectly fine, your issue is in the JS 

Comment: Thank you for your help, I understand very well :)

Comment: No problem, happy to help and explain  Sidenote, the other answer suggesting to change the code to `200` instead of `404` (or `422`) would have worked, but you probably don't want to be returning a `success` HTTP code with a nested property `success: true/false`; letting the status code reflect the `success`, and having a generic `message: 'Success'|'Failed'`, with an optional `errors: []` property makes more sense (in my experience anyway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your `response.errors.forEach` inside of your `success: function()`, but `422` (or any 400) code doesn't get handled by the `success` function, but rather the `error` function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#createBtn').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let form = $('#student-add').serialize();
    
    $.ajax({
      url: "{{ route('students.store') }}",
      data: form,
      type: 'POST',
      success: function (result) {
        if (result.success === true) {
          // Do whatever on `2XX` HTTP Codes
        }
      },
      error: function (response) {
        if (response.status === 422) {
          let responseJson = response.responseJSON ? response.responseJSON : { errors: [] };

          $('#ajax-validate ul').text('');
          responseJson.errors.forEach(function (item) {
            $('#ajax-validate ul').append('<li>'+item+'</li>');
          });
        } else {
          console.log('Unhandled Error:', response)
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Now when an 422 error is explicitly triggered, you code can properly handle the validation errors.